# Separating indices

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-optimization

Let $S\subseteq A^n$ for some finite alphabet $A$. I'm interested in finding a minimum subset $I\subseteq\{1,...,n\}$ such that for any two distinct $x, y \in S$, there exists an $i \in I$ for which $x[i]\neq y[i]$. I'm pretty sure this is a well known combinatorics problem but can't find any reference to it. Thank you!

Comment: If no such $i$ exists how can the two $x$ and $y$ be distinct?

Comment: For any distinct $x, y$, $i$ always exists, the problem looks for a *minimum* set of such indices separating each pair of elements of $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it as a [set covering problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) as follows. For each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, let binary decision variable $z_i$ indicate whether $i\in I$. The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^n z_i$ subject to linear constraints
$$\sum_{i: x_i \not= y_i} z_i \ge 1 \quad \text{for all $x,y\in S$ such that $x\not= y$}.$$

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much